# Complex domain URL structure with RESTful

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm building a RESTful wrapper around quite complex underlaying domain. I built a domain model using UML packages and classes and derived REST-resources from the meaningful classes.

When it came to the endpint-URL design, I decided to map the package/class structure directly to URLs in order to streamline the process and have a neat traceability between my logical model (domain) and physicall implementation (REST API).

Let's say I have a following domain extract:

[image]

Admin and Work are packages, while User, Permission and Task are classes (REST Resources).

I derived the following endpoint URLs from this domain:

- **mydomain/admin/user**   -> Users collection
- **mydomain/admin/user/id**    -> User instance with id
- **mydomain/admin/user/id/permissions**  -> All permissions of the User with id
- **mydomain/work/task**, and so on...

A collegue of mine noticed that the URLs are not optimal, mainly because these "package" parts do not map to the concrete resources. For example "admin" is not a Resource and is part of the URL. As the domain structure grows, there will be even more these intermediary non-resource-segments in the URL and he finds it wrong.

I find it nice, as URL structure itself tells something about the resource and is backed up with a complete, well documented domain model.

Is this a violation of RESTful standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a violation of RESTful standard?

No. REST has no opinon on how an URL should look. You could use an URL like

```
/foo/bar/baz?qux=12
```

without violating any REST principle. Such an URL has no meaning for a human reader but that doesn't matter.

It is not necessary that every parts of an URL like

```
/foo
/foo/bar
```

maps to a resource. In fact is is a common  misconception that RESTful URLS must follow some pattern or build rule. That is not the case.

Of courese there are best practices commonly used. One such practice would be to have *collection resources* like

```
/mydomain/admin/user
```

and *single resources* like

```
/mydomain/admin/user/42
```

But, again, that is not required by REST.

Answer (score 3):

The REST architecture doesn't dictate what your URL's should look like. So, from that perspective, you're not violating any rules.

Instead, an important aspect of REST is that one should be able to use hyperlinks in order to navigate from one URL to another (something we are all used to when browsing HTML websites, but is not as common in REST APIs). Using links, consumers of your web application (wether they are humans using a web browser, or other applications that are using your API) can discover the available URLs, and the actual structure of your URLs doesn't really matter. Your URLs can even change without breaking other applications, because they will simply follow the link to the new URL.

So from a REST perspective, you could use whatever URL structure you like. As long as you provide a fixed entry point that provides a link to your users collection, the actual URL could be anything.

However, it is obviously still helpful when URLs are easy to understand and somewhat predictable. For instance, right now you have collections with a singular URL (**yourdomain/admin/user**) and collections with a plural URL (**yourdomain/admin/user/3/permissions**), which isn't very consistent. I'd suggest using only plural names, so **yourdomain/admin/user** becomes **yourdomain/admin/users**.

As for your actual question, as I mentioned this doesn't matter from a REST perspective. More important is that the URL makes clear what it represents. Something I'd take into consideration is the amount of different endpoints you're gonna have. If you are building a small application, with a small amount of endpoints, I'd keep it simple. But if you are creating a very large application with a lot of domain models, prepending them with some kind of categories sounds like a good idea.

## Conclusion

URLs in a REST API should be discoverable by hyperlinks, and therefore no hard rules exist. Just make sure your URLs make sense to anybody who has to dig into them.

Some tips for usefull URLs can be found in [REST-ful URI design](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/).

Answer (score 2):

You aren't following the strict definition of being RESTful; but it's not due to your colleague's concerns.

Your main challenge is that your proposal has the endpoints baked in to the client applications. A client looking for a user goes straight to **/mydomain/admin/user**.

But if (and when) you re-locate that endpoint, say **/mydomain/admin/department/user**, your clients are now broken.

The solution:

REST defines that you have one (or very few) endpoints, termed "Cool URIs", which are fixed enough that they never change.

Instead of your client going to the endpoint of **/mydomain/admin/user** they will take this approach:

1. Retrieve a root object from **/mydomain** (the Cool URI). => "mydomain" service object.
2. "mydomain" object contains a URI which has the identifier of "admin". Follow that URI.
3. "admin" object contains a URI which has the identifier of "user". Follow that URI.
4. "user" object returned (more likely a list of users).

In this respect, there is no reliance upon the client application having to know the URI format; therefore when you change the endpoints, you just change the URIs that your service embeds in the returned REST objects.

This approach to REST, where each returned object contains the URI to the next, is part of the [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) principle.

If you're worried about how a client will pull back a given ID number (e.g. user 42), then that's catered for too: you can implement something like OData. So again, the URI is provided by the parent object. Instead of the client using a pre-baked endpoint like this:

- **/mydomain/admin/users/42**

...it instead does this:

1. **/mydomain** (Cool URI)
2. Follow the link for "admin".
3. Follow the link for "users", appending ?$filter=UserId eq 42

There are also some really good concepts around solving object versioning issues, which again are difficult if you take the approach of hard-coding the endpoints upfront.

If it's any consolation, I started off defining my REST architecture around fixed endpoints (as you are), and then discovered that using a true RESTful approach is actually simpler in the long run.

Best of luck!